# How to serve a mobile app

Tags: wcf, azure, mobile, appharbor

What would be a good way to provide a non-trivial backend for mobile apps, regarding both the protocol used for communication, and the actual hosting?

Most backend platforms (such as parse.com) provides some basic API for performing trivial CRUD data operations, but if the server logic needs to be more complex than that, what would be a good strategy (preferably .NET/C#, secondarily JAVA, but *not* javascript or any custom scripting approached)? SOAP web services (for example WCF)?

Regarding hosting, I have looked at Azure and AppHarbor, but can't decide between the two. AppHarbor seems like the only place to co-locate the web server and a MongoDB instance in Northern Europe, as Azure (apparently) only provides MongoDB in a US region. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're asking all about opinions, on both the technology side and the hosting side. Doesn't fit here.

Comment: Not really: all questions about architecture contains an element of opinion. I am asking about how to build a non-trivial backend stack for mobile apps. What have people actually seen working as service protocol,  and what hosting options have people actually had success with? Examples and explanatory comments are sufficient. Or anything else, that can clarify what to do in this aspect.